# Three step activation UI like Google account activation with next and back button

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to implement a three step activation process UI in android just like Google does in account activation,
Should i use multiple activity or fragment with separate layout? or is there any other best method to do that?

also i like to launch wifi setting activity with next and previous button within that, same as google does if network is not available.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use fragments to achieve multi step activation.

Also place a [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) betweeen switching fragment if you planning to make a n/w or DB call.

And for launcing WIFI you can use

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: yes am looking for some thing like dat, but it is much heavy for my purpose.. looking for a simple implementation

Comment: Yes,you can go for light weighted implementation using viewpager and fragments